# Persisting ActiveRecord objects across requests in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, request

I am trying to figure out a way to persist ActiveRecord objects across requests in the most efficient way possible.

The use case is as follows: a user provides some parameters and clicks "show preview". When that happens, I am doing a lot of background computation to generate the preview. A lot of ActiveRecord objects are created in the process. After seeing the preview, the user clicks "submit". Instead of recomputing everything here, I would like to simply save the ActiveRecord objects created by the previous request. There is no guarantee that these two requests always happen (e.g. the user may opt out after seeing the preview, in which case I would like to remove these objects from the persistence layer).

Are there any proven efficient ways to achieve the above? Seems like it should be a common scenario. And I can't use sessions since the data can exceed the space allotted to session data. Moreover, I'd rather not save these objects to the DB because the user hasn't technically "submitted" the data. So what I am looking for is more of an in-memory persistence layer that can guarantee the existence of these objects upon executing the second request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can save you a lot of unnecessary work by just saving it to the DB and not add other not-really-persistent-layers to your app.

A possible approach: Use a `state` attribute to tell, in what state your record is (e.g. "draft", "commited"). Then have a garbage collector run to delete drafts (and their adjactent records) which haven't been commited within a specific timeframe.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if not saving the object in a dirty state would be the best option as you could manage this with some sort of control attribute like state or status.

Having this would also be pretty great as you could validate data along the way and not do it until the user decides to submit everything. I know Ryan Bates has a screencast to create this sorts of complex forms (http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms).

Hopefully it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason the data can exceed the space allotted to session data because you're using cookie based sessions? If you need more space, why not use active record based sessions? It's trivial to make the change from cookie based sessions and is actually the recommended way (so why it's not the default I don't know)